# AutoMapper ProjectTo: Not working with nested objects

Tags: c#, linq, automapper

I have the following dto:

```
public class SingleForm
{
    // other props left out for brevity

    public List<Filter> Filters { get; set; }
}
```

I then try mapping it with AutoMapper like so:

```
CreateMap<Form, SingleForm>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Filters, 
        opts => opts.MapFrom(src => 
            Mapper.Map<List<Filter>>(src.Questions)));

CreateMap<FormQuestion, Filter>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Header, 
        opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.Question.QuestionText));
```

I then use ProjectTo:

```
var query = this.context.Forms
    .Where(e => e.Id == message.FormId)
    .ProjectTo<SingleForm>()
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

However, my filters collection is empty when I execute the query.

When I try to manually map the collection using LINQ, like below, it works correctly, so I'm wondering if I am doing something wrong?

```
var query = this.context.Forms
    .Where(e => e.Id == message.FormId)
    .Select(e => new SingleForm
    {
        Id = e.Id,
        Filters = e.Questions.Select(q =>
            new Filter { 
                Header = q.Question.QuestionText 
        }).ToList()
    })
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, I think it is best to avoid calling Mapper.Map() within your profile configuration. With this in mind, I think changing your first mapping to the following may help:

```
CreateMap<Form, SingleForm>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Filters,
        opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.Questions));
```

Answer (score 0):

If the mapping happens out side DbContext then should using includes method to retrieve all relationships items which nit able to lazy load without DbContext.

Comment: That's kind of the point of ProjectTo() - see [Automapper Queryable Extensions](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Queryable-Extensions)